# How to convert an array of 27 bytes where each 3 bytes is a 2's complement number into its numeric equivalent?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, twos-complement

I want to unpack a data package that has 9 numbers, each number is in a 2's complement format with 3 bytes. Thus 27 bytes in my package.
I have this, which allows me to use `struct.unpack` with 4 byte numbers but multiplies my numbers by 16.

**Works but multiplies output by 16**

```
data = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

a = a[:3] + [0] + a[3:6] + [0] + a[6:9] + [0] + a[9:12] + [0] + a[12:15] + [0] + a[15:18] + a[18:21] + [0] + [0] + a[21:24] + [0] + a[24:27] + [0]

ch0, ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4, ch5, ch6, ch7, ch8 = struct.unpack('>lllllllll', bytearray(a))
```

For 2's complement with 4 bytes I would have to add 0xFF to the front of negative numbers and 0x00 to the front of the positive numbers.

Is there a smart way to perform that? What is the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: If it multiples output by 16, why not just do `ch0 >> 4` after, which divides `ch0` by 2^4 = 16?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest parsing your 3-byte values as a single signed byte and an unsigned (16-bit) short. You can then use mathematical operators to recombine them into single number.

Here's a list comprehension that does it all in one step (given `s` as a `bytearray` or `bytes` string):

```
[(a<<16) + b for a, b in zip(*([iter(struct.unpack('>'+'bH'*9, s))]*2))]
```

The inner-most part does the parsing as I described above, using `struct.unpack`. Then I use the `zip` on two copies of the same iterator to get the byte/short pairs (this is a nifty trick!), and left-shift the byte by 16 bits before adding them together.

If you already have your bytes as unsigned integers, you don't even need to use `struct.unpack`, you can combine them directly in groups of three (with only a little bit of logic to get the sign right on the first byte):

```
[((a if a < 128 else a-256)<<16) + (b<<8) + c for a, b, c in zip(*([iter(data)]*3))]
```

Comment: From the solutions presented, yours was the fastest. I `%timeit` and got `100000 loops, best of 3: 4.85 µs per loop`.  I am still a little bit lost on how you got the values back together. If you could talk about it in more detail. One more thing. I had to `s = bytearray(data)` prior to usage (for future reference)

Comment: Yeah, `s` should be a bytestring or bytearray with the data in it. The one tricky bit (which I noted as such) is getting the byte-short pairs out of the tuple returned by `struct.unpack`. The `zip(*([iter(x)]*2))` bit is a neat recipe for getting pairs from the iterable `x` (a slightly different version of this is in the `itertools` recipes, under the name `grouper`). Once you have the parsed value in pairs, getting them into a single integer value is not hard. Just left-shift the byte (which we parsed as signed), and add it to the unsigned short.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a helper function to extend the sign-bit of the third byte to make a fourth one:

```
import struct

data = [0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0xff, 0xff, 0xff,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x02,
        0xff, 0xff, 0xfd,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x04,
        0xff, 0xff, 0xfb,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x06,
        0xff, 0xff, 0xf9,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x08]

signed = lambda v: [0xff if v & 0x80 else 0x00,]
ch = [struct.unpack('>i', ''.join(map(chr, signed(data[i]) + data[i:i+3])))[0]
                                                    for i in range(0, len(data), 3)]

print(ch)  # -> [0, -1, 2, -3, 4, -5, 6, -7, 8]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Really nice use of a lambda function. I `%timeit` and it provided me with `100000 loops, best of 3: 4.85 µs per loop`. 10 times slower then @Blckknght solution.

Comment: I got the wrong paste for the output and I could not edit it. Your function executed in ``100000 loops, best of 3: 15.2 µs per loop`

Comment: So, it's about 3 time slower than Blckknght's. Not surprising considering the numerous function calls being made (besides the one to the lambda).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python 3, use the class method [`int.from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes).  It can handle byte clusters of any length:

```
#!python3
data = bytes([0,0,0,0xff,0xff,0xff,0,0,1,0xff,0xff,0xfe,0,0,3,0xff,0xff,0xfd,0,0,4])
for i in range(0,len(data),3):
    print(int.from_bytes(data[i:i+3],'big',signed=True))
```

Output:

```
0
-1
1
-2
3
-3
4
```

There is also `to_bytes`, if you need to generate them as well:

```
>>> (-2).to_bytes(3,'big',signed=True)
b'\xff\xff\xfe'
```

Comment: Interesting solution. However I have to use 2.7. But I will definitely keep this in mind for the future.